# sp_getapplock @lockResult Return Code position

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions, deadlock

the following stored (named "sp_getNextObj") procedure preform *select*, *update* and *insert*

```
DECLARE @LockResults int
BEGIN  TRAN
    EXEC @LockResults = sp_getapplock 
        @Resource =  'sp_getNextObj',
        @LockMode =  'Exclusive', 
        @LockOwner =  'transaction', 
        @LockTimeout =  '3000'

        IF @LockResults<0
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK
            RETURN
        END

    UPDATE ...

    INSERT INTO ...

    SELECT * FROM ...

    -- release the SP lock
    EXEC sp_releaseapplock @Resource =  'sp_getNextObj'
    COMMIT
END
```

i use **sp_getapplock** to set the code in **lock area**,

the question is:

is the condition need to be after the body of the sp or before, means: when the @LockResult get it value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sp_getapplock will serialize access to a critical section within a block of code in a stored procedure. It can be within the body of the stored procedure protecting the portion you want to serialize access to.

If the code between the `sp_getapplock` call and the subsequent `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` calls a stored procedure named X then that stored procedure will be protected only within the context of the caller with the lock. Other commands can call X outside of the context of the code with the lock.

```
PROCEDURE Y
BEGIN
    DO SOME STUFF
    ...
    LOCK HERE --> Critical Section
        ...
        CALL X
    COMMIT OR ROLLBACK HERE --> Release Lock
    ...
   DO SOME STUFF
END
```

Comment: in my situation i protect this sp itself, is it mean that whole sp lock when  the thread is in the sp?

Comment: Then you need to put the transaction/lock call at the beginning of your stored procedure. As long as the lock name does not change then each call to the stored procedure will result in exclusive execution. Just be sure to always release the lock prior to returning from your proc.